# Eating food that is tamei

Tags: halacha, food, eating, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

What is the status (both *mid'oraita* [on the biblical level] and *mid'rabanan* [on the rabbinic level]) of a person who ate food that is *tamei* [ritually impure] as a *rishon le'tumah* [first level of *tumah* e.g. touched someone/thing that had touched a corpse]? Would that change if the food was a *sheni* [second level]?

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20279/759

Comment: @DoubleAA This question is a little broader; that one seems to be _nidda_ specific

Answer (score 2):

Explicit Mishna in [מסכת טהרות](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h65.htm) (Ch.2 Mishna 2 and onwards) and codified by the Rambam in הלכות [שאר אבות הטומאות פרק יא](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/a511.htm)

> יב  [י] האוכל רביעי שבקודש, אסור לו לאכול את הקודש; ומותר ליגע בקודש, ואינו פוסלו.  אפילו תבשיל שנתערב בו הקודש, ואין בו כזית בכדי אכילת פרס--הרי זה לא ייאכל ברביעי של קודש אלא בחמישי, שהוא טהור כמו שביארנו.‏
>
> יג  [יא] האוכל שלישי שבתרומה עצמה, או של חולין שנעשו על טהרת התרומה--הרי זה אסור לאכול את התרומה, עד שיטבול; ומותר ליגע בתרומה, והרי היא טהורה:  באכילה, עשו מעלה; בנגיעה, לא עשו מעלה.‏
>
> יד  במה דברים אמורים, בתרומה עצמה.  אבל תבשיל שנתערבה בו תרומה--אם אין שם כזית בכדי אכילת פרס--הרי זה מותר לאכול מאותו תבשיל, כדרך שהוא מותר ליגע בתרומה.‏
>
> טו  [יב] האוכל שלישי שבתרומה, או של חולין שנעשו על טהרת התרומה--אף על פי שהוא טהור לנגיעת התרומה, הרי הוא כשני לעניין קודש:  שטהרת התרומה, טומאה היא אצל הקודש.  אבל האוכל שלישי שבחולין שנעשו על טהרת הקודש, הרי הוא טהור--שאין לך שעושה רביעי בקודש, אלא קודש מקודש בלבד.‏

These are all MiDrabanan, as the Bartenura (ibid) says:

> אלו משמונה עשר דבר שגזרו בו ביום.‏

I.e. that they are (the first 3) of the 18 things decreed - as described in Mas. Shabbat Ch. 1 Mishna 4 - see the רע"ב there for a full list. Here's the relevant part:

> האוכל אוכל שהוא ראשון לטומאה או שני לטומאה , גזרו שיהא נעשה גופו שני לטומאה, ופוסל את התרומה במגעו, ששני פוסל בתרומה, הרי אלו שתי גזירות, אוכל אוכל ראשון, ואוכל שני. והשותה משקין טמאים  נעשה ג''כ שני לטומאה ופוסל את התרומה הרי שלש . וטעמא דגזור בהני, דזמנין דאכיל אוכלין טמאים ושדי משקין דתרומה בפומיה בעוד שהאוכלים טמאים בפיו ופסיל להו, וזמנין דשתי משקין טמאים ובעודן בפיו שדי אוכלין דתרומה בפיו ופסיל להו.‏

Comment: Can you translate please for those of us who don't understand the original?

Comment: @Matt - the titles above each Hebrew section are a synopsis; translating these sections will not make them any easier to understand, for those who have not learned the original.