# Menstruating women on public transportation

Tags: niddah, vehicles-transportation

In Leviticus 15:20, it says that anything a menstruating woman sits on is unclean.  Then, in verse 23, it says that if a man sits on something a menstruating woman has sat on, then he is unclean.
I have been to Israel twice, and I rode on public transportation both times, and I do not recall this ever having been an issue.  Nor am I aware of it being an issue when flying on El Al, the national airline.
Am I missing something, or is there a reason why this is no longer an issue, or maybe there is no reason it just isn't an issue anymore (in which case I will just drop the question)?

Todah.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20279/759 (https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25714/759)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments stated -- without a Temple today, we basically assume we're all "ritually impure" and don't worry about it beyond that. This isn't particularly about women, by the way  -- the guy who bumped into you on the bus may have been an mortician and recently touched a corpse, so you'd be "ritually impure" from that too. But all of this is of no particular consequence right now.

Comment: Source??????????

Comment: It doesn't matter if he's a mortician.  He could have gone to a funeral 10 years ago and it would still be the same thing.

Comment: @Heshy The problem is that a mortician probably attends a funeral almost daily - At least, he's probably in the room where the body is, at some point. I assume that by "he" you mean someone else? WHat if the person was sprinkled with Red Heffer blood and went to the mikvah, etc.?

Comment: @DanF Do you know anybody who was sprinkled with Red Heifer blood?