# consequences of minor tumah nowadays

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, teruma, kodshim, maseches-zavim

In a comment on [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95971) that is now deleted, DoubleAA said something to the effect of

> Yes you become impure by sitting on the seat, but anyone who needs to care about the consequences of becoming impure knows about them and acts accordingly.
>
> <sub><sup>(someone feel free to edit if you have access to deleted comments)</sup></sub>

What are the consequences nowadays of becoming tamei from midras ([see Zavim 4,1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Zavim.4?lang=bi))?  We don't eat terumah or kodshim or go into the Azarah because we're all assumed to be tamei from dead people anyway.

Comment: BTW you're working on a mistaken conception. FYI:  There are areas on the Temple Mount where a Tamei-Met (and corpse itself) may enter, yet Zav & Zava are forbidden entry.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yes I know.  That's why I said the azarah and not the Temple Mount.

Comment: @DoubleAA since you made the original comment, what did you mean?  that's the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10976/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio you were asking why we worry about strict forms of tumah.  I'm asking why someone would worry about lenient forms of tumah (midras in particular), since I've never heard of anyone nowadays caring about them until DoubleAA brought it up.

Comment: Ah, *from midras*.  Thanks; missed that somehow.

Comment: "we're all assumed to be tamei from dead people anyway" - maybe that's the mistaken assumption? (https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Parah.3.2)

Comment: @ba are there people doing that now?  I wondered why I'd never heard of them when I learned that mishnah.  I'd love to meet them!  Why don't we give them terumah?

Comment: @Heshy No idea, but it's possible in theory, so maybe that's what he meant, but I'm not sure if there's enough context for anyone else to answer

Answer (score 3):

The Ta”z and Magen Avraham (Orach Chaim 159:11) bring down an opinion that one should not have his hands washed for Netilas Yodaim, by a Nidah or others who are Metamai Be’midras, (and say that it is better  to follow that opinion)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.  But it doesn't really answer the question because those tumos (niddah, zavah, zav, boel niddah) have other consequences I already knew about - the obvious ones for niddah and zavah, and for the others, going on har habayis, eating challah in chutz laaretz, etc.

Comment: Being that a כלי שנטמא במדרס is מטמא other כלים, it would come out that it is preferable that the כלי that one uses for נטילת ידים should also be טהור from טומאת מדרס, otherwise the water would also become טמא